# Check if Bash script is compatible with sh

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sh

I have a script where it is defined `#!/bin/bash`, and I want to check if this script is compatible with `#!/bin/sh`.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: You may try: http://www.shellcheck.net/. However, it is not guaranteed to work even after you've checked that site. Basically you need to review every line manually because when an expression is syntactically correct, it does not mean that it will still do want you want.

Comment: Reading up on [Bashisms](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism) would be a good place to start.

Comment: Related: [Difference between sh and bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5725296/113632)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Being `sh`-compatible isn't, in itself, a goal. What issue(s) are you running into that requires your script work with `sh`? Depending on your reasoning different options may or may not be sufficient. If you simply need your script to run on most modern environments then using `bash` should be perfectly fine, and may actually be better than using `sh`, since `sh` maps to different shells on different platforms. On most modern environments it isn't actually its own binary but is just `bash` in [POSIX-compliant mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html), or another shell like `dash`.

If you really just need to make an existing Bash script work with the shebang `#!/bin/sh` you have several options:

1. Just run it as `sh your_script.sh` and see what happens - Bash is a superset of `sh` syntax, so many simple Bash scripts are valid `sh` scripts.
2. Run `sh -n your_script.sh` as rojomoke suggests, which will report syntax errors without actually executing the script (but may not catch all issues).
3. Manually audit your script for invalid syntax (John B's [Bashisms](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism) reference isn't a bad start), this obviously isn't a great solution but in practice it's the only way to be sure. If that seems daunting, well, it is :)

If you want/need to support `sh` the best option is simply to specify your script's shebang as `#!/bin/sh` - if it behaves as desired in the environments you need it to then it's (by definition) `sh`-compatible.

Note that you can write a `sh`-compatible script that still isn't POSIX-compliant, since many standard utilities like `grep` have their own POSIX-compliant feature sets you'd need to respect too. Again though, being POSIX-compliant isn't an end in itself, and I'd encourage you to confirm you really need to support POSIX before trying to be compliant with the standard.

I asked a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34805372/113632) you might find helpful too.

Comment: @hek2mgl yes, it's `dash` on Ubuntu, as mentioned. My point in (1.) is that trying to be `sh` compliant is (often) not that important. What else is "plain wrong/useless", exactly?

Comment: The fact that /bin/bash in POSIX mode might be used for /bin/sh does not mean that it will run any script written for bash.

Comment: @hek2mgl I don't believe I said that anywhere - in fact I said the opposite: "*many simple* Bash scripts are valid `sh` scripts". This implies there exist Bash scripts, particularly non-trivial ones, which are not valid `sh` scripts.

Comment: Before the discussion goes into the wrong direction, what I want to say is that the task "Make a shell script POSIX compaible" is not trivial and there is no general solution. While you'll first make sure that you will not use *bashisms* in the shell syntax itself, you'll further make sure that any programs like `grep`, `sed`, `awk` etc. etc. etc. will being called in a posixly correct way which can be endlessly painful, depending on the script.

Comment: @hek2mgl feel free to post your own answer. As best I can tell I'm trying to convey the same thing as you (ideally, just don't try to be `sh`-compatible). Note though that OP isn't (directly) asking for POSIX-compliance, simply `sh` compatibility. Granted they're connected, but they are separate goals.

Comment: Well, unfortunately I don't have an answer :) If you can control the environment in which your scripts are running: make sure they run bash (and friends). If not, probably use something else like Python e.g. if applicable. If not, developing the script in a strict POSIX environment might be a better start.

Answer (score 4):

Running the script with the `-n` option will parse and read the commands, and report syntax errors, but will not execute the code.

```
sh -n <scriptname>
```